When was this photo taken?

Taken approximately at the intersection of Lighthouse Avenue and 13th Street in Pacific Grove California, looking west.  I assume the large sampling of cars will help indicate roughly when the photo was taken.  Although there are probably lots of knowledgeable car enthusiasts in "Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair" who can identify the vehicles, I didn't post there in case the question would be considered off-topic.

I had tried to find the Coca-Cola billboard with Google Lens, but didn't have any luck.

The furthest left car is definitely a 1941 Chevrolet Master, and the car just to the right of that is some sort of mid-30s Studebaker. All of the other cars look similar or older, so I don't think they will be a better help than that Coke ad.

The large building in the background on the right is likewise no help in dating the picture accurately. It is the Holman Building, a local landmark. As shown in the picture it dates to 1931, when a fourth floor was added plus a restaurant on the roof.

Well, Forrest Gump isn't on the bench but that might be him approaching on the right sidewalk, if that is any help. But maybe the allowing parking in the middle of the street might actually be a helpful dating range.

@civitas Based on Google StreetView, there is parking in the median of Lighthouse Avenue to this day. Based on historical photographs it seems to have been there since at least the 1930s.

My Dick And Jane first reader in 1961 showed Spot hitching a ride on their car's running board. I didn't even know what a running board was, as I had never seen one on the road at that point. So I would hazard that this picture is taken much closer to 1948 than even 1961; and certainly no scene looked like this outside a Hollywood back lot in the mid or late 1960's.

Can you share the source of the photograph?

The shell sign with neon border could be from around 1942.

@njuffa Google streetview also shows that the Victorian houses on the left as well as the opposite modern concrete business building on the right still exist.

Between (more likely) 1948 and (highly unlikely) 1969
The logo on the gas station gives us a slightly later start date than the Coke ad requires.

Seen here is the Chevron "winged V" emblem introduced in 1948 and used up until 1969.

The presence of the 1947 Coke ad and 30s/early 40s cars suggests the early side of that range.

One official publication of the winged Chevron logo dates to June of 1948, but it is for the "wrong" product class (that is, not refined oil products): Official Gazette of the United States Patent Office, Vol. 611, June 1948, p. 770. I am still trying to find the earliest publication of this logo in the USPTO gazette.

Earlier official publications of the winged Chevron logo (though neither of them for the class of petroleum products): Official Gazette of the United States Patent Office, Vol. 598, May 1947, p. 23 ::
Official Gazette of the United States Patent Office, Vol. 602, September 1947, p. 193

Yeah they would have copyrighted the design well ahead of the rollout, which would have been an undertaking of several years across all owned & franchised locations.

Agreed. The information in the Gazette indicates that Standard Oil of California filed applications for the winged logo in 1946 and 1947, depending on product class. I basically wanted to find out how early in 1948 they could have rolled out the new gas station signs. My take is that this could have happened by first half of 1948. I am still trying to find out when Coca-Cola stopped using the "Girl at porch rail" image in their advertising to bracket the timeline from the other side.

There also appears to be a Shell sign a little bit to the right of the Chevron sign, although it could also be something else. Shell seems to have changed logo designs in 1948 and 1955, but I can't tell for sure which one this might be. It might be this design with the outer neon contour lit. Although that looks like the 1948 design, a similar neon sign seems to have been produced already in 1942.

It's of course possible that older logos persisted beyond the rollout of the new one, but the proposition that this photo is from after 1969 is only slightly more ludicrous than that it is from any time in the 1960s or even late 50s.

"Basoline"? huh?

The ad for Coke seen on the billboard on the right of the picture was first used in 1947. Various matching images can be found on the internet, for example here, but so far I have not been able to find one on a website (such a museum) that is not ephemeral. The copyright was registered on June 1, 1947:
Catalog of copyright entries, Third Series, Volume I, Part 11 B, Number 1, Commercial Prints and Labels, January-June 1947, Washington, D.C.: Copyright Office of the Library of Congress, p. 16:

Come over for Coke. (Girl at porch rail) (Soft drink) 7 sheets. Print. © 1 Jun 47; KK13533.

I assume that copyright was registered prior to publication, which dates the picture here to June 1947 at the earliest. I do not know how long Coke ad campaigns would typically run. Searching publications for Coke ads from the relevant time frame, I find that Coca-Cola seems to have switched images and slogans quite frequently, so one might assume use of this image for roughly one year.
I found a small print ad belonging to the same campaign that used a black outline of the ad image in The Lake Placid News, December 3, 1948, p. 10. Assuming the full-color billboard version was used for the same amount of time, this would date the picture to December 1948 at the latest. I searched for several hours trying to find later uses of this ad image but came up empty-handed.

When you say, “date the picture to December 1948 at the latest”, you mean that it would be evidence that the ad was still in use at that date, right? Because the presence of the ad in The Lake Placid News doesn’t mean that this photo couldn’t have been taken later than December 1948 – the billboard in the picture here could easily still have been hanging there a year later. (And of course, it could also easily have been taken down and replaced with something else on that particular billboard before December 1948, even if the campaign itself was still running.)

@JanusBahsJacquet Ad campaigns using specific images usually only run for a particular length of time. In my limited understanding, this is typically a year. Billboards in active use get updated regularly, every few months based on what I have observed. Therefore the approximate last known use of a particular ad image puts a reasonably tight upper bound on the timeline. I searched several hours for uses of this particular one and found some uses in 1948, but none in 1949. I also observe that Coca-Cola introduced new ad images frequently around this time.

There's a magazine ad from 1947 with the same woman in a scene with a couple of people in the background that is more obviously a porch.  I would guess that the billboard ad was adapted from the print ad for a simpler presentation.  Are you certain the copyright is for the billboard?  Could the billboard have been from a few years later than the print ad?

@phoog My assumption is that the "7 sheets" mentioned in the copyright application refer to different variants of the same image, adapted for different media (billboard, full-color magazine such as National Geographic or Life, newspaper, etc.).

@njuffa https://www.coca-colacompany.com/about-us/history/history-of-coca-cola-advertising-slogans This list seems to back up your general timeline.

Adding to the consensus above, the car in the foreground right has a California license plate that was issued between 1947-1950.  See Wikipedia for historical license plate images.
The car in front of it seems to have the older license plate format (tough to see) from 1946.  Which would place the date most likely in 1947.

Were California license plates replaced with renewals? Currently in Maryland, and I presume most if not all other states, unless you sell/transfer a car to a new owner the license plates could be unchanged for decades - you just get stickers for each periodic renewal. If the same was true in California then the full 1947-1950 range would be plausible.

In Michigan in the 1960s (my childhood), new license plates were issued every year or two, rather than a sticker to add to the plate. Specifics are fuzzy, but lots of people's garages had a collection of their (same car) license plates hanging on the wall.

From what I can tell, new plates were issued every few years (1947 being one of them).  From 1947-1950, the same plate was used but instead of stickers, they issued "validation tabs" that were screwed in over the date.  See this image.  It doesn't look like the 1947 license plate has one, but the image isn't sharp enough to rule that out.

A few general tips that will help you in dating other pictures as well.
The vehicles span a range of about 12 - 14 years, late 20's to early 40's.
If this were a Hollywood recreation, they most likely would've used a narrower range so they wouldn't have to "Age" the older cars.
With vehicles from the 40's, and no war bond ads, that puts it post WW II.
Without doing any in depth research I see nothing that would put it later than about 1949 because in the 50's cars were getting more affordable, making it more likely to see one that was less than a year old, and yet no cars from the 50's are in the photo.
So without any in depth research at all, I place it between 1946 and 1949.

The dark car approaching on the left is likely an early 1940s Chevrolet DeLuxe, judging by the shape, grille lights and other decorative features. The 1939 models appear to have looked quite different, setting a lower border for the year.
